# Pig: field does not exist after join

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, inner-join

It seems I'm somehow removing a key after join.

**Context**

The goal is to get all records from table_2 that consist only of distinct member ids from table_1.

As a novice, I'd appreciate pointers in best-practices to achieve this goal and any comments on why I get the "projected field" error.

**What I've tried**

```
-- assume %default vals set for path_1 and path_2 to data

-- load the data

table_1 = LOAD '$path_1' as (day, member_id, country);
table_2 = LOAD '$path_2' as (day, member_id, country);

-- get distinct member_id's from table_1

table_1_ids = DISTINCT(FOREACH table_1 GENERATE member_id as member_id);

-- get all records from table_2 that only have table_1_ids

new_table_2 = JOIN table_1_ids BY member_id, table_2 BY member_id;
```

**the error**

Invalid field projection. Projected field [member_id] does not exist in schema: table_1_ids::member_id:bytearray,table_2::day:bytearray, table_2::member_id:bytearray, table_2::country:bytearray.

Comment: if useful: in Python's Pandas this would be as simple as: new_table_2 = table_2[table_2['member_id'].isin(set(table_1['member_id']))]

Comment: Hi Quetzalcoatl, one thing which i notice is member id which needs to be member_id in the last line of the pig script --> new_table_2

Comment: Also please check the way you are doing distinct in this script --> table_1_ids

Comment: Fixed member id to member_id. Any further advice?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's as simple as loading with differently named member_id fields e.g.  table_1 = LOAD '$path_1' as (day, member_id_1, country);
table_2 = LOAD '$path_2' as (day, member_id_2, country); and then joining on member_id_1 and member_id_2

Comment: Just break the step with DISTINCT into two steps, it will work. I tried with my own dataset, with DISTINCT they way you did not work. But, with two separate steps, did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @piyush and @Nazar for the comments.
One way to get the desired result is to i) uniquely label the keys to join on and ii) separate the distinct statement:

```
table_1 = LOAD '$path_1' as (day, member_id_1, country); 
table_2 = LOAD '$path_2' as (day, member_id_2, country);
all_table_1_ids = FOREACH table_1 GENERATE member_id_1 as member_id_1;
distinct_table_1_ids = DISTINCT all_table_1_ids;
new_table_2 = JOIN distinct_table_1_ids BY member_id_1, table_2 BY member_id_2;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you didn't provide the script after join, but I assume you have some set of `generate` statements. After join all columns are renamed to `<alias_name>::<field_name>`. As you have field(`member_id`) with same name in both aliases, after join you can't refer to it by it's simple name. You'll have to use it's full name `table_1_ids::member_id` or `table_2::member_id` (they have the same value, but they are still 2 different fields in join result). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, the :: syntax is also helpful in this case.